# Signout function is not working in nextjs with laravel API

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, axios

I am using laravel sanctum for API authentication. I will provide all data related to registration, signin and signout. I have included `HasApiTokens` in `User.php` and imported it as well.

I didn't include `\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,`  in `kernal.php` since I am only using Sanctum for api authentication.

registration.js

```
async function handleRegistration (e) {
e.preventDefault()
const formdata = new FormData()
  formdata.append('name', name)
  formdata.append('email', email)
  formdata.append('password', password)

        
  if(name && email && emailValidation(email) && password  && password.length >=6 && cPassword && cPassword === password) {
     try {
         const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/registration', formdata)
            if(response.status === 200) {
                console.log(response)
                router.push('/signin')
            } else {
                setRegistrationError('Error registerring')
            }
        } 
        catch(error) {
            // window.alert ('Error during registration:', error);
            setRegistrationError(error.response.data.error);
            console.log(error.response.data.error)
        }
    }
}
```

registration route in api.php

```
Route::post('/registration', [UserController::class, 'registration']);
```

registration method in controller

```
public function registration(Request $request) {
    $credentials = $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);
    
    // Check if the email is already taken
    $existinguser = User::where('email', $credentials['email'])->first();
    if($existinguser) {
        return response()->json(['error'=>'Email already in use'], 400);
    }
    
    $user = new User;
    $user->name = $credentials['name'];
    $user->email = $credentials['email'];
    $user->password = bcrypt($credentials['password']);
    $user->save();
    return response()->json(['message'=>'User created successfully']);
}
```

signin.js

```
async function handleLogIn (e) {
e.preventDefault()
if(!email) {
  setErrEmail('Enter your email')
} else if(!emailValidation(email)) {
  setErrEmail('Enter a valid email')
}

if(!password) {
  setErrPassword('Enter your password')
}

if(email && password) {
  let item={email, password}
  try {
const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/signin', item)
    
    if(response.status === 200) {
      localStorage.setItem('user_info', response.data.user.name)
      localStorage.setItem('user_email', response.data.user.email)
      localStorage.setItem('user_id', response.data.user.id)
      localStorage.setItem('user_type', response.data.user.usertype)
      localStorage.setItem('api_token', response.data.token)
      router.push('/')
      console.log('User Successfully Logged in.')
    } else {
      setsigninError('Error logging in', error)
      console.log('error A')
    }
  } catch(error) {
    if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
      setsigninError(error.response.data.error);
      console.log(error.response.data.error)
  } else {
    setsigninError('Error logging in');
  }}}
 setPassword('')
}
```

signin route in api.php

```
Route::post('/signin', [UserController::class, 'signin']);
```

signin method in controller

```
public function signin(Request $request) {
    $credentials = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required | email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $user = User::where('email', $credentials['email'])->first();
        // $user = auth()->user;
        // $user = Auth::user()->id;
        if ($user && Hash::check($credentials['password'], $user->password)) {
            $token = $request->user()->createToken('api_token')->plainTextToken;
            return response()->json(['user' => $user, 'token' => $token]);
        }
    }
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Email or password is incorrect'], 401);
}
```

signout function in some nextjs component

```
const api_token = localStorage.getItem('api_token');

async function logOut() {
    
    const confirmLogout = window.confirm('Are you sure you want to log out?');

    if(confirmLogout) {
        try {
            let response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/signout', {}, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${api_token}`
                }
            })
            // if(response) {
                console.log(response.data)
                localStorage.clear();
                router.push('/');   
                window.location.reload();   
            // }
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    }

}
```

signout route in api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->post('/signout', [UserController::class, 'signout']);
```

signout method in controller

```
public function signout(Request $request) {
    $request->auth()->user()->tokens()->delete();

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Logged Out'], 200);
}
```

.env

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:+30Ftdj9RMgLOv3zK/0L6voXVbRU/yiBMcRaxQh5JAQ=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug


DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=amazon
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DISK=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120


MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailpit
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="hello@example.com"
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_HOST=
PUSHER_PORT=443
PUSHER_SCHEME=http
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
VITE_PUSHER_HOST="${PUSHER_HOST}"
VITE_PUSHER_PORT="${PUSHER_PORT}"
VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME="${PUSHER_SCHEME}"
VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

The questions I have are as below.

1. When I try to logout, I got `AxiosError: Network Error` as `alert`.
2. If I try to use `$request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();` in signout function, it says `Undefined variable currentAccessToken` and saying I called `currentAccessToken` on `null`. I think it means `user()` is `null`.
3. I am running both `npm run dev` in one terminal in `vscode` and `php artisan serve` in another terminal in `vscode` but laravel server stopped working every 30 seconds. I had to stop the server manually again using `CTRL + C` and rerun it again using `php artisan serve` then it stopped working around 30 seconds or after it accepts one request.
4. I cannot signin in Postman as well. I got the following error when I tried to sign in in Post man.

   Could not send request
   POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/signin
   Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8000
5. After I signed in, I don't think laravel doesn't know that I have signed in since I cannot use `auth` facade in controller. `Auth` returns `null`. `auth()->user` returns `null`. `auth()->user()` returns `null`.